# Enable SSO login in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Need help enabling SSO login in Oracle APEX application, my company supports SAML 2.0, they are asking me what nameid will be used. I don't know if SSO is an option in APEX or not? Any help is appreciated guys. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This article should give you some guidance:

https://insum.ca/saml2-single-sign-on-with-oracle-application-express/

**TL;DR**

1. Use Apache HTTPD as a web proxy for APEX.
2. Install and configure the mod_auth_mellon module for the web server.
3. Set up the application on the identity management system of choice.
4. For the APEX application, use the HTTP Header Authentication Scheme. The HTTP Header variable should have been configured when mod_auth_mellon was installed and set up.

HTH.

Comment: This answer is 2 years old, so I'm just going to add that in the upcoming APEX v21.2 (https://apex.oracle.com/en/platform/features/whats-new-212/), we can expect to have SAML support out of the box. Kudos to the APEX team and the late Joel Kallman (https://twitter.com/chrisneumueller/status/1447895673899266051) for this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know *SAML*, but - as far as SSO in Apex is concerned, here's how to do that. See if it helps.

Suppose that there's an application which is used as a "menu" that lets you navigate through different Apex applications. In that menu application, go to

```
Shared Components 
  > Authentication Schemes 
  > choose Current scheme (e.g. "My menu auth. Scheme") 
  > Session Cookie Attributes > type MY_MENU_COOKIE into  „Cookie name“ field
```

If application menu is the list item, its query might look like this: it selects all applications available to user logged in as `:APP_USER` (those user:application pairs are stored in the `oper_x_app` table). Pay attention to `&SESSION.` - without it, it won't work:

```
select 
  null,
  app_name labelValue,
  'http://szg01lcp1.data.centar:8084/apex/f?p=' || id_app ||':1:&SESSION.' targetValue,
  null is_current                                        --     ^^^^^^^^^
from applications                                        --     This!
where id_app in (select id_app from oper_x_app
                 where username = :APP_USER
                )
order by app_name
```

Now, for all those applications, you have to do the same: navigate to

```
Shared Components 
  > Authentication Schemes 
  > choose Current scheme (e.g. "Copy of My menu auth. Scheme") 
  > Session Cookie Attributes 
  > type MY_MENU_COOKIE into „Cookie name“ field
```

Go to that application's

```
Navigation menu
  > Create list entry
  - name the entry "My apex menu" 
  - target type URL should look like this; &SESSION. is again important!

    http://your_server:8084/apex/f?p=118:1:&SESSION.
                                           ^^^^^^^^^
                                           This!
```

That's all; using the "My apex menu" navigation menu entry, you can go to the *central* place of your applications and switch among them without having to log on all over again.